# Unexpected result in if else statement

Tags: java, if-statement, joptionpane

I'm a beginner, so this result I am getting for one condition of my if else statement is blowing my mind.  Everything works properly except for the condition when the QtyCalc variable is >= 100.  The Finprice variable is listed as the disc variable and I can't figure out why.  Help?

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class SoftwareSales {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int price = 99;
        String Qty;
        double QtyCalc, preprice, Finprice, disc;

        Qty = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "How many packages will you buy?");
        QtyCalc = Double.parseDouble(Qty);
        preprice = QtyCalc * price;

        if (QtyCalc >= 100) {
            disc = (preprice * (0.5));
            Finprice = (preprice - disc);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your discount is: " + disc + ".\n" + "Your final price is: " + Finprice + ". ");
        } else if (QtyCalc >= 50 && QtyCalc <= 99) {
            disc = (preprice * 0.4);
            Finprice = (preprice - disc);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your discount is: " + disc + ".\n" + "Your final price is: " + Finprice + ". ");
        } else if (QtyCalc >= 20 && QtyCalc <= 49) {
            disc = (preprice * 0.3);
            Finprice = (preprice - disc);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your discount is: " + disc + ".\n" + "Your final price is: " + Finprice + ". ");
        } else if (QtyCalc >= 10 && QtyCalc <= 19) {
            disc = (preprice * 0.2);
            Finprice = (preprice - disc);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your discount is: " + disc + ".\n" + "Your final price is: " + Finprice + ". ");
        } else if (QtyCalc < 10 && QtyCalc >= 1) {
            disc = 0;
            Finprice = 0;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sorry, there is no discount for purchases less than 10." + " Your price is: " + preprice);

        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have entered an invalid number.");
        }
        disc = 0;
        Finprice = 0;

        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: You are making `disc` equal to the half of `preprice` and `Finprice` equal to the other half, therefore they are equal. What is wrong?

Comment: I've come to the conclusion that I should step away from the computer more often and have some coffee.  I completely missed the obvious there (slaps his forehead).  Thanks everybody for pointing that out and please don't laugh too much about it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The final price is equal to the discount when the quantity is >= 100 because the discount is 50% ... look at the code that you posted. In particular:

```
if (QtyCalc >= 100) {
    disc = (preprice * (0.5));
    Finprice = (preprice - disc);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your discount is: " + disc + ".\n" + "Your final price is: " + Finprice + ". ");
}
```

Comment: Ah, I've been staring at this screen too long without thinking about the right things.   Does the.. "No question is a stupid question" rule count here?  (I'll go hide in the corner now.. )  Thanks! :)

Comment: I know the feeling. Trust me, you are not alone ;)

Answer (score 0):

There is no strange behavior, just simple math:

```
        disc = (preprice * (0.5));
        Finprice = (preprice - disc);
```

you should also consider eliminating redundant code:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class SoftwareSales {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int PRICE = 99;
        String qty;
        double qtyCalc, preprice, finprice, disc;
        disc = 0;
        qtyCalc = 0;

        boolean invalid = false;
        do{
            invalid = false;
            qty = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "How many packages will you buy?");
            if (qty == null){
                return;
            }
            try{
                qtyCalc = Double.parseDouble(qty);          
            }catch(NumberFormatException e){
                invalid = true;
            }
        }while(invalid);

        preprice = qtyCalc * PRICE;
        if (qtyCalc >= 100) {
            disc = (preprice * (0.5));
        } else if (qtyCalc >= 50 && qtyCalc <= 99) {
            disc = (preprice * 0.4);
        } else if (qtyCalc >= 20 && qtyCalc <= 49) {
            disc = (preprice * 0.3);
        } else if (qtyCalc >= 10 && qtyCalc <= 19) {
            disc = (preprice * 0.2);
        } else if (qtyCalc < 10 && qtyCalc >= 1) {
            disc = 0;
            finprice = 0;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sorry, there is no discount for purchases less than 10. Your price is: " + preprice);
            return;
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have entered an invalid number.");
            return;
        }

        finprice = (preprice - disc);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, String.format("Your discount is: %.2f.\nYour final price is: %.2f. ",disc,finprice));

    }
}
```

Also remember the java-convention for variables: always begin with lower-case.
finals alsways IN UPPER-CASE

Comment: Thank you for the advice and edited code!  I'm very new to Java, so most of what I've learned is redundant.  I really appreciate the help.

Comment: ok, because you're new at java-programming, the code now is in java-naming-convention and less redundant. I also added java string format, which is a cool feature ;)